# Christoffel symbol in 2D Euclidean-Space

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

In 2D Euclidean space

straight line

in $(x,y)$ coordinate $x=x(s)$ and $y=y(s)$ satisfy

$$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}=\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}=0$$

is the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^a_{bc}=0$ in $(x,y)$ coordinate?

and how can I get the $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ in polar coordinate $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ ?

thanks.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Christoffel symbols are a measure of the first derivatives of the metric tensor. In particular, they will be zero if all derivatives are zero. In a euclidean space this will alway be the cas-e, not only in 2 dimensions!

For another coordinate system you can either use the definition ([e.g. from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols)), which can be complicated since in 4D for example there are 40 of them.

Or, which seems to be easier most of the time, compute the Lagrangian of a free particle (it is mostly easy in an easier basis), take the Euler-Lagrange-Equation and bring it in the form $\ddot x^i = \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot x^j\dot x^k$

This can be also seen as a definition of the symbols as coefficients it this equation. Now you can read out the desired Christoffel symbols from those coefficients.

Comment: Nice answer. Also your name is the same as mine irl spelling and all.

Comment: well, maybe my name is Horus in reality and I only took another forum name here... :-P

Comment: That would be super cool hehe.